# Use font from a compressed folder

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a compressed folder which contains a font (among other things) which I need to open and use. I know that I could extract the font to a temp folder and use it that way, but I would rather find a solution to keep it in memory if possible.

I am using System.IO.Compression to get the font as a stream but from then I am a bit stuck!

```
using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(filelocation, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry fontEntry = zipArchive.Entries.FirstOrDefault(ze => ze.Name.EndsWith("ttf"));
    if (fontEntry != null)
    {
        Stream fontStream = fontEntry.Open();
        // I need a TextBlock to somehow use this stream as the FontFamily
    }
}
```

I have looked at System.IO.Packaging to pack the stream and then try to load a font family using the package URI but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the path to the font as `c:\folder\file.zip\fontname.ttf`?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `PrivateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont` might work for you, I've never tried it before but it will probably do the job

Comment: Sorry John, I wont put tags in again.

Comment: Red Serpent, I have read elsewhere that PrivateFontCollection wont work with WPF?

Comment: DavidG, I don't think you can access a font within a fip file like that. I tried:
    FontFamily tff = new FontFamily(@"C:\Zipfile.zip\font.ttf");
and got Arial

Comment: try to put your font file inside your `WPF Project` and you can use that font in any system that doesn't have that font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you can use `System.IO.Packaging`. Supposing that "textBlock" is the control you want to use:

```
using (ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.Open(filelocation, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
{
    ZipArchiveEntry fontEntry = zipArchive.Entries.FirstOrDefault(ze => ze.Name.EndsWith("ttf"));
    if (fontEntry != null)
    {
        Stream fontStream = fontEntry.Open();
        Uri uri = CreateMemoryUriFromStream(fileStream);
        textBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily(uri, "myFont");
    }
}
```

Here the `CreateMemoryUriFromStream` method

```
public static Uri CreateMemoryUriFromStream(Stream stream)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] streamData = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(streamData, 0, streamData.Length);

    Package pack = Package.Open(memoryStream, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    Uri packageUri = new Uri("memory:");

    PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, pack);

    Uri packagePartUri = new Uri("/packagePart", UriKind.Relative);
    PackagePart packagePart = pack.CreatePart(packagePartUri, "application/font");

    Stream packageStream = packagePart.GetStream();
    packageStream.Write(streamData, 0, streamData.Length);

    return PackUriHelper.Create(packageUri, packagePart.Uri);
}
```

So no need to use a temp folder!

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Il Vic, but I have just tried your suggestion but Arial is being displayed on screen and when I examine the FamilyNames within the FontFamily, I just have one entry for en-us:Arial.

Comment: Indeed I used my solution in a WPF window and I can assure it works. If you wish, I can post my whole code. Anyway pay attention to your .ttf file. If it contains for example a bold font, your TextBlock must have its property `FontWeight` set to `Bold`, otherwise you'll see just the system default font (maybe Arial?).

Comment: I'm sorry Il Vic, you were absolutely right. I needed to add Regular to the end of the font name and then it worked.